# Determine if datetime object is date or datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to format datetime objects, and I wrote a little function to determine if the datetime object is a date or datetime object.  But, nothing I've tried works.

Generating date and date times with datetime.date.today() and datetime.datetime.now() and assigning that to dtDate.

My first attempt was isinstance() :

```
dtDate = datetime.date.today()
# dtDate = datetime.datetime.now()

if isinstance(dtDate, date) :
        sDate = dtDate.strftime('%x')
    elif isinstance(dtDate, datetime) :
        sDate = dtDate.strfttime('%x %X')
```

But that triggers regardless of whether it is a date or datetime.  If I am more specific, like 'datetime.date' says 'arg 2 must be type or tuple'.

I also tried to detect if the object had the hour field :

```
if dtDate.hour :
    sDate = dtDate.strftime('%x %X')
else :
    sDate = dtDate.strfttime('%x')
```

But, that freaks out if the object is purely a date, without an hour attribute.

Even a try/except block has issues :

```
try :
    if dtDate.hour :
        sDate = dtDate.strftime('%x %X')
except :
    sDate = dtDate.strfttime('%x')
```

This returns 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'strfttime' for date objects.

Lastly, I tried to compare types :

```
if type(dtDate) is datetime.date :
    sDate = dtDate.strftime('%x')
else :
    sDate = dtDate.strfttime('%x %X')
```

Returns properly for date, but not datetime objects (returns 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'strfttime')

Sorry for the brain dump, but I am completely out of ideas.

Comment: Note that the `strfttime` is a typo: i don't think that's a valid method for either date/datetime

Comment: In your call of `isinstance`, pass `datetime.date` and `datetime.datetime` instead. That's what is causing your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the `datetime` class (or simply command+click on `datetime` using an IDE on Mac), you'll notice that the `datetime` class actually is a subclass of `date`:

```
class datetime(date):
    ...
```

Therefore, `isinstance(dtDate, date)` will be true even if `dtDate` is a `datetime` object.

You can fix this by checking for the more specific type first:

```py
if isinstance(dtDate, datetime):
    sDate = dtDate.strftime('%x %X')
elif isinstance(dtDate, date):
    sDate = dtDate.strftime('%x')
```

Full code:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

#  dtDate = date.today()
dtDate = datetime.now()

if isinstance(dtDate, datetime):
    sDate = dtDate.strftime('%x %X')
elif isinstance(dtDate, date):
    sDate = dtDate.strftime('%x')

print(sDate)
```

Comment: I SWEAR I tried that.  Ha.  Thank you - I am glad the solution is simple.  Thank you very much!